# Defining a custom week using days of the month or year in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am running a simple query to get weekly revenue from our sales

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', payment_date) AS week, sum(payment_amount)  
FROM payment 
WHERE payment_date BETWEEN '2010-jan-1' AND '2016-dec-31' 
GROUP BY week
```

Now I need my week start and end date to be static for every year. All 52 weeks of the year need to be accounted for e.g.

```
Week 1: Jan 1-7
Week 2: Jan8-14
Week 3: Jan15-21
Week 4: Jan22-28
Week 5: Jan29-Feb4 and so forth
```

I did some investigation and figured out that I need a user defined function using the `payment_date` as argument and returning a week value. I can then call this function in the SQL query above, in place of the `date_trunc()` function.

How can I use an incremental loop to assign a week value to the `payment_date`?
Can I also use this return value in group by clause in the SQL query?
Some explanation with detailed examples will be highly appreciated since I have basic to intermediate knowledge of SQL.

---------------Edit--------------

I'm trying to use 2 functions now to take into account the leap year, where I would still want March 4th to be included in the 9th week. Ive tried to use the function by &klin and convert it to SQL, I keep getting "syntax error at or near 'int' on line 9. My code is below.

create or replace function is_leap_year(int)

returns boolean language sql as $$

```
select $1 % 4 = 0 and ($1 % 100 <> 0 or $1 % 400 = 0)
```

$$;

create or replace function week_no(timestamp)

returns int language sql as $body$

declare
    y int;
    day_shift int;
begin

```
y = extract(year from $1);

    day_shift = 1 + (is_leap_year(y) and $1 > make_date(y, 2, 28))::int;
    return ((extract(doy from $1)::int)- day_shift) / 7+ 1;
```

end

$body$;

SELECT week_no(payment_date) as week_number, sum(payment_amount)

from payment p join payment_event pe on p.payment_event_id = 
pe.payment_event_id

where payment_date between '2016-jan-1' and '2017-jan-1'
and pe.payment_event_type_id != 2

group by week_number

order by week_number

Comment: I think Feb 29 is going to cause you some trouble.

Comment: Yes I thought of that too, but I think just discarding it for now will do. I am happy to have that week every leap year with an increased revenue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `doy` (the day of the year) in the way like this:

```
create or replace function week_no(date)
returns int language sql as $$
    select ((extract(doy from $1)::int)- 1) / 7+ 1
$$;

with the_table(a_date) as (
values
    ('2017-01-01'::date),
    ('2017-01-07'),
    ('2017-01-08'),
    ('2017-01-14'),
    ('2017-01-15'),
    ('2017-01-22')
)

select extract(doy from a_date)::int as doy, week_no(a_date)
from the_table;

 doy | week_no 
-----+---------
   1 |       1
   7 |       1
   8 |       2
  14 |       2
  15 |       3
  22 |       4
(6 rows)
```

---

If you want to correct the week number so that March 4th is always in 9th week (even in a leap year), use this handy function:

```
create or replace function is_leap_year(int)
returns boolean language sql as $$
    select $1 % 4 = 0 and ($1 % 100 <> 0 or $1 % 400 = 0)
$$;
```

Your function may look like this (I've used the plpgsql language for better readability though this also can be coded as an sql function):

```
create or replace function week_no_corrected(date)
returns int language plpgsql as $$
declare
    y int = extract (year from $1);
    day_shift int = 1 + (is_leap_year(y) and $1 > make_date(y, 2, 28))::int;
begin
    return ((extract(doy from $1)::int)- day_shift) / 7+ 1;
end;
$$;

with the_table(a_date) as (
values
    ('2016-03-03'::date),
    ('2016-03-04'),
    ('2016-03-05'),
    ('2017-03-03'),
    ('2017-03-04'),
    ('2017-03-05')
)

select a_date, week_no(a_date), week_no_corrected(a_date)
from the_table;

   a_date   | week_no | week_no_corrected 
------------+---------+-------------------
 2016-03-03 |       9 |                 9
 2016-03-04 |      10 |                 9
 2016-03-05 |      10 |                10
 2017-03-03 |       9 |                 9
 2017-03-04 |       9 |                 9
 2017-03-05 |      10 |                10
(6 rows)
```

---

In an SQL function you cannot use variables, assignments may be replaced by derived tables:

```
create or replace function week_no_corrected(date)
returns int language sql as $$
    select ((extract(doy from $1)::int)- day_shift) / 7 + 1
    from (
        select 1 + (is_leap_year(y) and $1 > make_date(y, 2, 28))::int as day_shift
        from (
            select extract (year from $1)::int as y
        ) s
    ) s
$$;
```

Comment: Thank you. This works really well with what I want to do except that I will need to make some modifications because the 'days of the year' number will increase by 1 every leap year. I just need to take this into account as well.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to convert this to SQL and using Navicat to execute the query with the 2 functions. Can you help with the error please, Ive edited my question now.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are problems with your requirements.

> Now I need my week start and end date to be static for every year.

They can't be. Leap years happen. February 29 will either shift start and end dates one year out of every four, or you'll need to allow one week to have eight days.

> All 52 weeks of the year need to be customized for . . .

I think you mean that all 52 weeks need to be *accounted* for. But 52 * 7 = 364. You're missing a day.

I think the simplest expression that *calculates* a week number from a date is `(extract(doy from payment_date)::integer / 7) as week`. I don't know whether it's worth putting that into a function. Instead, I might start with creating a view that uses that expression.

But a calculation won't do anything special about February 29, or about the fact that every year has more than 52 * 7 days.

I really think your best bet here is to build a table instead of using a calculation.

```
create table weeks (
  calendar_date date primary key,
  week_num integer not null 
    check (week_num between 1 and 53)
);
```

Populate it with this dates for 2016 and 2017, and with *calculated* weeks, to give us a starting point. (2016 was a leap year.)

```
insert into weeks 
select 
    ('2016-01-01'::date + (n || ' days')::interval)::date as calendar_date
  , extract(doy from ('2016-01-01'::date + (n || ' days')::interval)::date)::integer / 7 + 1 as calencar_week
from generate_series (0, 730) n;
```

Let's look at week 9.

```
select * 
from weeks
where week_num = 9
order by calendar_date;
```

```
calendar_date  week_num
--
2016-02-25     9
2016-02-26     9
2016-02-27     9
2016-02-28     9
2016-02-29     9
2016-03-01     9
2016-03-02     9

2017-02-25     9
2017-02-26     9
2017-02-27     9
2017-02-28     9
2017-03-01     9
2017-03-02     9
2017-03-03     9
```

In 2016, the *calculated* week 9 ran from 2016-02-25 to 2016-03-02. In 2017, it ran from 2016-02-25 to 2017-03-03. But now that all these week numbers are in a table, you can adjust them any way you like. You can even change the adjustments from year to year if it makes sense to do that.

Answer (score 0):

By breaking your problem down to month-day strings it will allow you to use the same logic across multiple years

```
mysql> SELECT "01-07" < "01-08";
+-------------------+
| "01-07" < "01-08" |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

A simple date format of `%m-%d` works for comparing the payment dates to the week buckets you want to assign.

To manually assign all 52 week ranges, you can use a case statement:

```
SET @md_format="%m-%d";

SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (date_format(`input_date`, @md_format) < "01-08") THEN 1
    WHEN (date_format(`input_date`, @md_format) < "01-15") THEN 2
    WHEN (date_format(`input_date`, @md_format) < "01-22") THEN 3
    -- ... All other cases
    ELSE 52
  END;
```

[See the docs for the syntax to define a function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createfunction.html)

Functions will allow you to do operations like:

```
SELECT week_bucket(payment_date) `week`, SUM(revenue) `revenue`
FROM my_table
WHERE week_bucket(payment_date) > 13
  AND week_bucket(payment_date) < 15
GROUP BY `week`;
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I think that this code will take care of the Feb 29/leap year issue as well since I can custom define the end of each week. Can you please explain the  line 'SET @md_format="%m-%d";' I'm trying to figure this out by searching the syntax online but as I said I have limited knowledge of SQL, thanks.

Is there any other way to compare just the month and day to the actual date field, apart from using the SET statement